# How to deal with discontinuous path in brownian motion?

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, stopping-times

I'm having great difficulty trying to understand brownian motion. They require almost every path to be continuous, yet in proofs they assume *all* path are continuous. In quite a few questions I'm trying to prove, I need all path to be continuous too. Example: let $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ by closed, prove $T(\omega) = \inf\{t:B_t(\omega)\in K\}$ is a stopping time. My method is first let $U_\varepsilon = \bigcup_{x\in K} \mathcal{B}(x,\varepsilon)$,
\begin{equation}
 \{T>t\}= \bigcap_{x\in[0,t]} B^{-1}_x(K^c) = \bigcup_n \bigcap_{q\in [0,t]} B^{-1}_q(U_{1/n}^c)
\end{equation}
where $q$ is rational. I need every $\omega$ to be continuous for the second equality to hold.

Discontinuous paths also defeat the purpose of stopping time, since they can leap across the enclosed boundary used to define $T$. This is not possible for discrete random walk $S_n$, no walk can leap across the boundary. What to do about the discontinuous path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the trajectories of a Brownian motion $B$ are assumed to be a.s. continuous, i.e. there exists a measurable set $A$ of probability one such that on $A$ every trajectory is continuous, you can always define another Brownian motion $\tilde B$ to be equal to $B$ on $A$ and identically $0$ otherwise. This way, $\tilde B$ has **everywhere continuous** trajectories and $B=\tilde B$ a.s.

Now, $\tilde T$ (hitting time of $K$ for $\tilde B$) is a stopping time, and that is what you have proven. Since $T=\tilde T$ a.s., if the filtration is **complete**, then it readily follows that $T$ is also a stopping time.

Completeness is usually a key condition for hitting times to be stopping times (see the Debut theorem, e.g. [here](https://almostsuremath.com/2009/11/15/stopping-times-and-the-debut-theorem/)).